# C# Web Services changing a variable string to an int without error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I need to change my existing code to retrieve the authors by Id, but the `Id` is an `int`. It throws an error when I change it.

Here is my code:

```
public string[] GetAuthorsByName(string namePart)
{
    List<string> authors = new List<string>();

    foreach (var author in context.Authors
                                  .Where(a => a.Name.Contains(namePart))
                                  .ToList())
    {
        authors.Add(author.Name);
    }

    return authors.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: why not use Convert.ToInt32() and catch a NumberFormatException

Comment: If you've already got other code that references this method, then it might be better to simply overload this method to provide a GetAuthorsById **in addition** to the method you've listed above. @JhonnyRose provides an implementation for you to work with below.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the `Id` is a primary key - which means you'll always only return at most one author.

Consider using this method, returning a single `Author`:

```
public Author GetAuthorById(int id)
{
    return context.Authors.Find(id); 
}
```

And then...

```
Author author = GetAuthorById(5);
string authorName = author.Name;
```

Comment: The `Find` method also has the benefit of making use of EF's cache to prevent the same query being firing twice if the object is already tracked by the `DbContext`